# NERDTREE in vim replaced my Ctrl +O shortcut for going back

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Iḿ used to press Ctrl+o to go to the last position in the document but after installing NERDTree this keys are for opening Nerdtree pane.

is NERDTree offering a replacement or is there any other keys for the same function?

Comment: A cursory look at the docs for NERDTree doesn't reveal anything about using a `C-o` mapping.  What does the output of `verbose map <C-o>` report?